# Using "Raw MathLink Connections" to create a "Kernel Object"

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, kernel, remote-access, grid-layouts

Mathematica 8.0.0:

I am stuck trying to get a Mathematica Mathlink connection from my Windows computer working that should connects to Linux over network (or vice versa) and then launches a Kernel on the remote end (which I want to use to do some calculations on my Windows PC or vice versa).

For local connections it works on both operating system and I can use this Mathlink connection to launch a Kernel:

```
Needs[ "SubKernels`LinkKernels`"]
kernel = FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "MathKernel.exe"}];
link = LinkLaunch[kernel <> " -subkernel -mathlink"]

LaunchKernels[link]
```

I have already tried to create MathLinks on one computer (let's say IP: 192.168.1.1) where the kernel is launched with:

```
(*Computer which creates the remote link*)
kernel = LinkLaunch[First[$CommandLine] <> " -mathlink"];
    LinkRead[kernel];
    LinkWrite[kernel, Unevaluated[$ParentLink = LinkCreate["8000", LinkProtocol -> "TCPIP"];]]
```

But I cannot access this link when I use:

```
(*Computer which wants to use the remote link*)
link = LinkConnect["8000@192.168.1.1", LinkProtocol -> "TCPIP"]
LinkRead[link]
LinkRead[link]
LinkWrite[link, Unevaluated[$ProcessID]]
First[LinkRead[link]]
```

Somehow I am also missing authentication informations for the computer which wants to connect in my code but I did not get an example which shows me where to state these credentials.

Comment: I see you were new, when you posted your question. Have you read the [FAQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/faq) of our site?  If an answer helps you, you should upvote it. If it solves your problem, you should accept it. And if you want to discuss details, use the comment-function here or go to chat. Doing nothing might be considered as rude and it's unlikely (at least the same) people help you again.

Answer (score 5):

*Unfortunately*, I have only a Linux and a Mac combination here to try but maybe I can give some hints. First, you should setup your systems in your local network so you can [use ssh without password](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/).

Then you should carefully study Preferences->Parallel->Remove Kernels->Custom launch command. This things is likely to need some adjustment. On my Linux machine it looks like

[image]

It's obvios, that the "math" call will not work on my MacOSX machine where Mathematica is installed under `/Applications` and the terminal can not call it directly. Furthermore, the kernel is call `MathKernel`. After adjustment I used the following custom launch command

[image]

After this it worked instantly (I turned the local parallel kernels off):

```
LaunchKernels[]

(*
  {KernelObject[1, "192.168.1.116"], KernelObject[2, "192.168.1.116"],
  KernelObject[3, "192.168.1.116"],  KernelObject[4, "192.168.1.116"]}
*)

$SystemID
ParallelEvaluate[$SystemID]

(*
  "Linux-x86-64"
  {"MacOSX-x86-64", "MacOSX-x86-64", "MacOSX-x86-64", "MacOSX-x86-64"}
*)
```